# Is there a MarkDown shortcut for the Help Center like there was [faq] for the FAQ?

Tags: support, markdown, site-faq, help-center, meta-faq

In the limited markdown (for comments and chat, e.g.) we always had `[faq]` to link to the FAQ. Now that the FAQ has been changed to Help Center, do we have new syntax for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is! You can use `[help]`. This will be rendered as "[help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help)".

`[faq]` still works and links to the new help center, but I'd recommend you using the new syntax.

---

You **cannot** use these, although it might seem logical to you:

- `[helpcenter]`
- `[help-center]`
- `[hc]`