# Markdown help is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, site-faq, editing-help

With the recent burnination of the FAQ, tell-tale traces of it remain around the network. The [markdown help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) still states:

> - [faq], [faq#anchor], [meta-faq], [meta-faq#anchor] – link to the FAQ. Link text is "faq" (capitalization is respected). meta-faq only works on meta sites.

Which is slightly incorrect. All four link to their respective meta/main help center now (see [Is there a MarkDown shortcut for the Help Center like there was [faq] for the FAQ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184716/192187)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated the editing help page, and added a meta-help tag in 2013.7.1.6367

Comment: Do you work for SE? If so, why don't you put it on your profile page?

Comment: Yes and will do :)

Comment: Nice to see you joined the SE team. :)